# How to create shortcut in the homescreen for 'Favourites' tab in Dialer?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-apollo, phone-app, adw.launcher, samsung-touchwiz

I'm using Samsung Galaxy 3 (GT-I5801). The ones listed as Dialer.favourites and contacts.starred in the 'Choose custom activity' are not working. This happens in both TouchWiz and ADWLauncher

Comment: What do you mean "not working", what happens?

Comment: nothing happens! :( The resulting icon is unusable. clicking on it invokes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Dialer One](https://market.android.com/details?id=kz.mek.DialerOne) as your dialer or even if you install it but use the default stock dialer app, you can get to the Favorites screen by long pressing a blank area of the homescreen, and from the SHORTCUTS menu, choosing FAVORITES.

Comment: It works like a charm. It is better than stock dialer in many other ways too. Thanks for suggesting it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use Launcher pro as my Default homescreen and I can have a favorite contacts shortcut by doing the following steps:

1.Press the menu button and select the Shortcuts option

2.Then select the Activites option

3.Then select Contacts-->Phone

4.Give it a name

5.There must be a Favorites Shortcut